# How to insert javascript into xml(website)ODOO

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo-8

I want to download multi images from website, pls check my javascript and xml code, what's wrong with my code?

And how to insert that javascript into xml?

Here is my javascript code

```js
var zip = new JSZip();
var count = 0;
var zipFilename = "zipFilename.zip";
var urls = [    
    'http://google.com/image1',
    'http://google.com/image2',
    'http://google.com/image3'
];

urls.forEach(function(url){
    var filename = "filename";
    // loading a file and add it in a zip file
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
        if(err) {
            throw err; // or handle the error
        }
        zip.file(filename, data, {binary:true});
        count++;
        if (count == urls.length) {
            var zipFile = zip.generate({type: "blob"});
            saveAs(zipFile, zipFilename);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my xml

```html
<a href="#" onclick="urls();">Download</a>
```

Comment: This question is very unclear.  You're meant to add supporting text in order to explain your problem and your current approach to resolving it, with an explanation of expected results and current results.  As it is you're asking how to add Javscript to XML and then posting some HTML.  Unless this question is explained better then you're unlikely to get any help (and it's likely to end up closed).

Comment: Your question is still unclear.  Why do you want to insert Javscript into XML?  Can you please explain the practical result that you are trying to achieve, not what you are trying to do to achieve it?

Comment: Sorry, no.  That's HTML, not XML, and I don't understand why you want to insert Javscript into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert Javascript into website xml you need to create a record template that inherits the  website assets  as follows -

```
<template id="custom_assets" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend" name="Custom Assets">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/...path to your custom js file"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: check console error and please share it with me

Comment: What I see is that you are calling a function named - urls() on click of the anchor tag. But you haven't defined function with same name in javascript. This might be creating console error - urls is not defined. I guess.

Comment: Try using something like this --

    odoo.define(['jszip'], function (jszip) {
        "use strict";
       //your custom code here

    });

Comment: Okay I will write complete JS for you. It will be like -

odoo.define(['jszip', 'ods'], function (jszip, ods) {
    "use strict";

//use ur js code from here - starting from -
var zip = new JSZip();
.   
.
.
.         saveAs(zipFile, zipFilename);
        }
    });
});
});

Comment: To add JS in xml use the code I have given it to you into your any xml file that is included in __openerp__.py.

Comment: Is the JS issue resolved?

Comment: which version odoo you are using?

Comment: I checked it right away on my browser, And it works fine. May be some issue with your core js files. Did you include your JS file into the XML?

Comment: Where you want that particular button to be displayed. It might be a template wherever you need that button.

Comment: Please create a new question. Send me it's link. We can continue there.

Answer (score 1):

Your final JS will be like -

```
odoo.define(['jszip', 'ods'], function (jszip, ods) {
"use strict";
    var zip = new JSZip();
    var count = 0;
    var zipFilename = "zipFilename.zip";
    var urls = [    
       'http://weedo.sgeede.com/website/image/product.template/376_339fb36/image',
       'http://dota-everyday.com/support/image',
      'http://dota-everyday.com/omniknight/image'
    ];

urls.forEach(function(url){
    var filename = "filename";
    // loading a file and add it in a zip file
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
    if(err) {
        throw err; // or handle the error
    }
    zip.file(filename, data, {binary:true});
    count++;
    if (count == urls.length) {
        var zipFile = zip.generate({type: "blob"});
        saveAs(zipFile, zipFilename);
    }
});
```

});
});